# JSF 2 Injection problem thus application will not deploy to Glassfish server

Tags: jsf-2, cdi, inject

I am injecting a `List<Reception>` to a `ReceptionService` class but all i get is an error and the project won't deploy: The error i get is:

```
Unsatisfied dependencies for type List<Reception> with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject com.github.adminfaces.starter.service.ReceptionService.selectedPatients
  at com.github.adminfaces.starter.service.ReceptionService.selectedPatients(ReceptionService.java:0)
```

I have set `bean-discovery-mode="all"` to beans.xml already

The `PatientList` Class  where `List<Reception> selectedPatients` has its getter and setter methods

```
import com.github.adminfaces.starter.model.Reception;
import com.github.adminfaces.starter.service.ReceptionService;
import org.omnifaces.cdi.ViewScoped;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class PatientListMB implements Serializable {


    @Inject
    ReceptionService receptionService;

    Integer id;

    LazyDataModel<Reception> patients;

    Filter<Reception> filter = new Filter<>(new Reception());

    List<Reception> selectedPatients; //patients selected in checkbox column

    List<Reception> filteredValue;// datatable filteredValue attribute (column filters)
```

The `ReceptionService` class where i am injecting `List<Reception> selectedPatients`

```
package com.github.adminfaces.starter.service;

import com.github.adminfaces.starter.infra.model.Filter;
import com.github.adminfaces.starter.infra.model.SortOrder;
import com.github.adminfaces.starter.model.Reception;
import com.github.adminfaces.template.exception.BusinessException;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static com.github.adminfaces.template.util.Assert.has;

/**
 * @author rmpestano
 *         Reception Business logic
 */
@Stateless
public class ReceptionService implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    List<Reception> selectedPatients;
```

Comment: Please improve the code  formatting etc in your question

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you're using [admin-starter](https://github.com/adminfaces/admin-starter/) as reference project, if you look at the code you'll see there is a `producer` method in [Utils.java](https://github.com/adminfaces/admin-starter/blob/f507560493853aa78efbbd4215f4ebb8de59fd7b/src/main/java/com/github/adminfaces/starter/util/Utils.java#L48-L51) which is responsible for creating the list of cars.

Bringing it to your project you just need to create a producer method which returns a list o List or instead of using Injection you can simple remove the `@Inject` and instantiate the list and add the objects manually.

Comment: The problem was that I had not created a producer method. I added a UtilsReception class and everything now works fine. I prefer using the injection method because it looks more organized. Thanks @rmpestano